# React, Losing styles after array.map()

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

I have a array of objects.

In my React Component, i have a block of html code:

```
    <div class="item">
      <div class="card card--big">
        <div class="card__cover">
          <img src="img/covers/cover2.jpg" alt="" />
          <a href="#" class="card__play">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-play"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card__content">
          <h3 class="card__title"><a href="#">Benched</a></h3>
          <span class="card__category">
            <a href="#">Comedy</a>
          </span>
          <span class="card__rate"><i class="icon ion-ios-star"></i>7.1</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

If i paste him manualy - All Works Great, but if i use Array.map, styles are losing (Card size is wrong).

```
  const elements = content.map((content, index) => {
    return (
      <div class="item">
        <div class="card card--big">
          <div class="card__cover">
            <img src="img/covers/cover2.jpg" alt="" />
            <a href="#" class="card__play">
              <i class="icon ion-ios-play"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="card__content">
            <h3 class="card__title"><a href="#">Benched</a></h3>
            <span class="card__category">
              <a href="#">Comedy</a>
            </span>
            <span class="card__rate"><i class="icon ion-ios-star"></i>7.1</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  });
```

How I can fix that?

Comment: In react we don't use `class` but `className`. You know that?

Comment: Yeah, i fix class / classNames error, but that doesn't resolve my problem.

Comment: Can you create demo on codesandbox?

Comment: Sorry, project is very big, i can't create codesandbox-demo

Comment: No problem. I meant just the part with maping array with cards (with styles included). But nevermind, don't bother

Answer (score 0):

I took your card html markup for `item` div and ran it in jsFiddle to see if card sizes change. It worked normally. Check the code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kudp0yg7/).

```js
function CardList() {
  var content = [
   { id: 1, name: 'card 1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'card 2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'card 3' },
  ];
  
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      {content.map((item, index) => (
        <div className="item">
          <div className="card card--big">
            <div className="card__cover">
              <img src="img/covers/cover2.jpg" alt="" />
              <a href="#" className="card__play">
                <i className="icon ion-ios-play" />
                {item.name}
              </a>
            </div>
            <div className="card__content">
              <h3 className="card__title"><a href="#">Benched</a></h3>
              <span className="card__category">
                <a href="#">Comedy</a>
              </span>
              <span className="card__rate"><i className="icon ion-ios-star" />7.1</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<CardList />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;  
}

.item {
  margin: 1rem;
}

.card {
  padding: .5rem;
  background-color: #21D4FD;
}

.card.card--big {
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is coming from the parent element before .item class. you need to correctly style whatever the parent element is. for instance, if the parent div className is .wrapper you can style it to a 100vh then style the item height in percentage like 80% for instance. this will force the item height to be uniform. you can also use display: flex on the parent element if the width is the problem.